# Get Exception properties from MassTransit Fault message

Tags: c#, masstransit

I would like to be able to access properties on the original exception that is thrown from a Consumer inside a Fault Consumer. For example, if the unhandled exception is a `ValidationException` with a collection of Errors, am I able to access that collection from a Fault Consumer?

The only thing I seem to have access to is the ExceptionType and the Message. I suppose I could parse the exception message to get the Errors collection, but is there a way to achieve this without parsing the message and generating the collection?

```cs
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<MyMessage>> context)
{
    string exceptionType = context.Message.Exceptions[0].ExceptionType;
    string exceptionMessage = context.Message.Exceptions[0].Message;

    if (exceptionType == "FluentValidation.ValidationException")
    {
        // here I want to get the Errors collection on the exception of type ValidationException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MassTransit does not serialize `Exception`, it encapsulates the exception details in an `ExceptionInfo` type that is included with the `Fault` event.

There is no access to the original `Exception` type, and for good reason. Serializing exceptions as part of a message contract is just bad practice, in my opinion.